# NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In Core2.0-Angular I created a SPA application where I was adding the Kendo-Charts component. I created a link on the nav and added the component to the app.module.shared.ts folder.
This is the graph.component.html page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ChartsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts'
import { AppComponent } from '../app/app.component';

import 'hammerjs';

@Component({
selector: 'graph',
template: `
    <kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
        <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
        <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
        <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
        <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
        </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
`
```

})

```
export class GraphComponent {
private series: any[] = [{
    name: "India",
    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
  }, {
    name: "Russian Federation",
    data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3]
  }, {
    name: "Germany",
    data: [0.010, -0.375, 1.161, 0.684, 3.7, 3.269, 1.083, -5.127, 3.690, 2.995]
  },{
    name: "World",
    data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
  }];
  private categories: number[] = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011];
```

}

And this is the error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

So what do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Server prerendering needs separate configuration for the server-side and client-side rendering when Angular animations are used to avoid errors, triggered from the fact that client objects like window, document, etc. do not exist on the server.

The NoopAnimationsModule has to be used in the server-side configuration, while the BrowserAnimationsModule - in the client-side one:

[Using Kendo UI for Angular with ASP.NET Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/dotnet-core/#toc-troubleshooting)

[Sample app config](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular-universal-demo/tree/master/aspnet_core_sample_application/ClientApp/app)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with the ASP.NET Core 2.0 Visual Studio 2017 template.  I moved the import 'hammerjs'; from the app.shared.module.ts to the app.browser.module.ts.   And as provided by @topalkata you will want your animations separated between browser and client.  "The NoopAnimationsModule has to be used in the server-side configuration, while the BrowserAnimationsModule - in the client-side one:"  I would have just commented on topalkata's answer but I can't comment yet.